# Load multiple url from text file in php

Tags: php

I have this php , and I want to extract the title from multiple url that I have in url txt

this is the php code , and doesn't work, I don't know why ,

In the url txt I put the url, like this

1
2
3
etc.

and the output is only for the first link, and I don't know why.. can somebody help me ?

```
function getTitle($url){
@$str = file_get_contents($url); 
if(strlen($str)>0){
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
} else {
    return false;
}

}
$urls = file("url.txt");

foreach($urls as $url)
{
$title = getTitle($url);
if($title === false)
{
    continue;
}
echo $title;


}
```

Comment: Your function declaration is missing a closing curly brace

Comment: @nimmneun I have solve this , but the same output.. I don't know why ..  I have receive the output only for the first link. and nothing for the rest of links.